# laravel inertia how to infer typeof InertiaFormProps?

Tags: typescript

I have a page that uses the `useForm` hook, this page is a multi-step form that are seperated into their own component.

Something like this:

```
    export default function create(){
    
      const form = useForm({
        name: '',
        content: '',
        is_published: 0,
        some_more_fields_here
      });
    
    
    return (
    <div>
    <GeneralPageInformation form={form} />
    
    
    <SeoInformation form={form} />
    </div>
    )
}
```

the form object that `useForm` returns looks like this:

```
 InertiaFormProps<{name: string, content: string, is_published: number, rest of your fields}>
```

now I tried doing something like this

```
interface IGeneralPageInformation {
  form: InertiaFormProps;
}
```

while this does give me access to stuff like `form.processting` and `form.recentlySuccessful`

the keys like `name` and `content` are not visible when trying to use something like `form.setData('all available keys should show up here))`

I could manually declare the keys like this

```
interface IGeneralPageInformation {
  form:  InertiaFormProps<{name: string, content: string, is_published: number, resf of the fields}>
}
```

But this is obviously not a very "scalable" solution as I would have to manually edit every form whenever it's changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Vue 3,

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { InertiaForm, useForm } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3"

const form: InertiaForm<{
                title: string,
                category: string,
                types: Array<string | number>
            }> = useForm({
                title: "",
                category: "",
                types: [],
            })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React, you can do it like this:

```
import { InertiaFormProps } from '@inertiajs/react/types/useForm'
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/react'

interface FormInterface {
  email: string
  password: string
}

const MyReactForm = () => {
  // Pass in your type as a generic like below 
  const { data, setData }: InertiaFormProps<FormInterface> = useForm({
    email: '',
    password: '',
  })

  return (
    <form>
      <input
        id='email'
        type='email'
        onChange={(e) => setData('email', e.target.value)}
        value={data.email}
      />
      <input
        id='password'
        type='password'
        onChange={(e) => setData('password', e.target.value)}
        value={data.password}
      />
    </form>
  )
}

export default MyReactForm
```